# What to do when there is only one valid value to be used in the Cauchy-Riemann equations

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I just did 2 problems where the $u$ part of the C-R equation was $0$. I'll give one as an example. I'm confused as to what conclusions I can correctly arrive at.

$$f(z)=Im(z)$$

So I can say that $v=y$ and $u$=0. Thus,

$$u_x=0$$
$$v_y=1$$

And,

$$u_y=0$$
$$v_x=0$$

So because the first 2 equations don't match, could I say that $f(z)$ is not differentiable anywhere?

Comment: in complex analysis, all the theorems are based on $f(z)$ being complex differentiable on an open connected subset of $\mathbb{C}$ (for example the neighborhood of a point )  so forget about differentiability only at one point.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right because the first $2$ equations don't match, you can say that $f(z)$ is not differentiable anywhere

[Cauchy–Riemann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations)

Comment: The iff part is not right. $\Rightarrow$ is always true, but $\Leftarrow$ sometimes fails.